# get function from superclass after overloading superclass function c++

Tags: c++

I have a superclass with these function :

```
    Superclass& operator<<(const char *str);
    Superclass& operator<<(int num);
    Superclass& operator<<(void(*pf)());
```

and subclass that I rewrited with these function :

```
Subclass& operator<<(const char *str);
Subclass& operator<<(int num);
```

And I want to know if I can go get the `Superclass& operator<<(void(*pf)());` function to my subclass

Comment: Do you want just a pointer to the function, or do you want to make a call to the base (super) class function?

Comment: @RSahu make a call to the base (super) class function

Comment: See the duplicate. The same syntax can be used for non-`virtual` member functions as well.

Comment: @RSahu thanks - solve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call the super class function use the super class name, like this:

```
Superclass::operator<<(void(*pf)());
```